# Convert factor to numeric in R

Tags: r

I’ve a data set (myData) that contains numerical, factor, and categorical variables. One of the variable, let’s call it $x$ is a factor and I’m trying to convert it to numeric. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information), and this is what I used

```
### Convert myData$x from factor to numeric
myData$x <- as.numeric(levels(myData$x))[ myData$x]
```

it seems it works, but I got this warning message:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Is that something I should be worried about? And how can I fix it?

Comment: This means that there are non-numeric elements as levels which got coerced to `NA` by `as.numeric`.  If you don't need the warnings, then use `?suppressWarnings`.  I think this warning is a friendly reminder that your data column is not all `numeric`

Comment: as akrun said, it is nothing but read this post to understand it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984989/how-to-avoid-warning-when-introducing-nas-by-coercion

Comment: Many thanks akurn and Nemo for the comments. This was very helpful to me! +1