# Obfuscate string in R

Tags: r, encryption

I have a password that I store in a plain text file. I want to obfuscate it somehow, in case someone is looking at my monitor.

Ideally, I would like to encrypt a password with another default string (say, "123") and get an obfuscated version of my password. Then, when I need password within a code, I want to decrypt the password with the same string "123". It would be also good that the lengths of obfuscated and normal passwords differ.

So, the logic should be:

```
encrypt(password, "123") -> obf_string
decrypt(obf_string, "123") -> password
```

How can I do this?

P.S. I know that it's not secure anyway, but this is what I want to have right now.

Comment: Andrie de Vries wrote a good article about this problem: https://www.r-bloggers.com/securely-storing-your-secrets-in-r-code/

Comment: Although the first article is more useful: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/11/how-to-store-and-use-authentication-details-with-r.html

Comment: If you are dealing with passwords, don't encrypt/decrypt; rather, use hashes. For instance `digest::digest(password)` returns an hash you can safely put in codes. When an user enters a password, you match the hash of it with the "correct" one, so you don't have to decrypt. See the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: @nicola the thing is I need to pass that password later on, so it's not me matching passwords.

Comment: @NJBurgo, I read this article, but didn't find solution to what I specified.

Comment: When the server is attacked the attacker will obtain the encrypted passwords and the encryption key. Try to find a way that does not include encryption the passwords.

Comment: Define the attacker, their capabilities and the value of the passwords. If you are passing the passwords along to 3rd party services you become the attack point, your security needs to be better that the 3rd parties you are passing the password to. You become exactly the target an attacker is looking for, the easiest way to compromise the 3rd party sites. The 3rd parties security, no matter how good is reduced to your security. Consider that it is your users who are at risk from poor password handling, they expect and deserve good security.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to obfuscate is through random number generation, here my attempt:

```
encrypt <- function(password, string){
        set.seed(password)
        encr <- round(runif(nchar(string), 0, 9))
        y <- as.integer(substring(string, seq(nchar(string)), seq(nchar(string)))) + encr
        return(y)
}

decrypt <- function(password, string){
        set.seed(password)
        encr <- round(runif(nchar(string), 0, 9))
        y <- paste0(string - encr, collapse="")
        return(y)
}
```

Your string is e.g. `1984`. You just have to pick a password, e.g. `2016`.

```
> encrypt(2016, "1984")
[1]  3 10 16  5
```

You give them to `encrypt()` and the function returns a numeric vector of the same size of your string. To get back the string use `decrypt()` with your password and the vector:

```
> decrypt(2016, c(3,10,16,5))
[1] "1984"
```

A less naive alternative, that further allows text connections, is to encode/decode through `base64`, using the [base64enc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/base64enc/base64enc.pdf) package:

```
install.packages("base64enc")
library(base64enc)
base64encode(c(2,0,0,6))
base64decode("AgAABg==")
```

Comment: Good idea! Is it possible to eliminate installing additional package to get string immediately when encrypt?

Comment: I see that `set.seed` only interprets integers, not strings. Any way to change it?

Comment: @000andy8484 Base64 is just an encoding, hardly secure.

Comment: As I said, I need obfuscation. I don't care about security.

Comment: If security is not needed just use the password. If it is just obfuscation an attacker will not find that to be a problem.

Comment: f there is no attacker why do you want to obfuscate the passwords?

Comment: I don't understand, surely running as.integer on a vector of strings just returns a warning and a vector of NAs?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @zach comments, this procedure would not be safe in case of an attack. This is uniquely useful is you want to obfuscate a string (e.g. from someone passing by and looking at the screen), security is not implied in this question.

This version of my the functions I reported in the previous answer also accepts strings with numbers and letters:

```
obfuscate <- function(password, string){
        set.seed(password)
        vec <- substring(string, seq(nchar(string)), seq(nchar(string)))
        encr <- y <- vector("list",length(vec))
        letters <- rep(letters,2)   # prolongue letters sequence
        for (i in 1:length(vec)){
                ifelse(is.numeric(vec[i]),             # extracting encryption numbers 
                       encr[[i]] <- round(runif(1, 0, 9)),   # if numeric
                       encr[[i]] <- round(runif(1, 0, 26)))  # if letters

                ifelse( !is.na(as.numeric(vec[i])) ,   # encrypting
                        y[[i]] <- as.numeric(vec[i]) + encr[[i]],                    # if numeric
                        y[[i]] <- letters[which(letters==vec[i])[1] + encr[[i]]] )  # if letters
        }
        return(unlist(y))
}

reveal <- function(password, y){
        set.seed(password)
        for (i in 1:length(y)){ 
                ifelse(is.numeric(y[i]),             # extracting encryption numbers 
                       encr[[i]] <- round(runif(1, 0, 9)),   # if numeric
                       encr[[i]] <- round(runif(1, 0, 26)))  # if letters
                ifelse( !is.na(as.numeric(y[i])) ,   # encrypting
                        y[[i]] <- as.numeric(y[i]) - encr[[i]],                   # if numeric
                        y[[i]] <- letters[which(letters==y[i])[1] - encr[[i]]] )  # if letters
        }
        return(paste0(unlist(y), collapse=""))
}
```

Here is an example:

```
> obfuscate(2016,"a6b8")
[1] "f"  "10" "x"  "11"
Warning messages:
1: In ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(vec[i])), y[[i]] <- as.numeric(vec[i]) +  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(vec[i])), y[[i]] <- as.numeric(vec[i]) +  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Note that the number of warnings is equal to the number of non-numeric characters. This could be suppressed with `suppressWarnings()` as explained [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984989/how-to-avoid-warning-when-introducing-nas-by-coercion). My preference is for always expressing R warnings.

```
> reveal(2016,c("f","10","x","11"))
[1] "a6b8"
Warning messages:
1: In ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(y[i])), y[[i]] <- as.numeric(y[i]) -  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(y[i])), y[[i]] <- as.numeric(y[i]) -  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: While inventing enctyption is fun it is a bad idea to use it, again: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break. Futrther there is no assurance that `set.seed` is the same between systems or between software releases.

Comment: We got the point @zaph, but Sergey needs "to obfuscate somehow" a string not to recreate the enigma machine. Security is not involved in this specific question.

Comment: You named the functions `encrypt` and `decrypt`. Since it uses a key it does seem to qualify as encryption. Also, not knowing `r`, in generall warning message are not a good thing.

Comment: @zach I replied to your comments in the edited answer.

Comment: @Sergey I updated the function to allow character strings, could you please follow up or accept?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, for example the following produces an error: reveal(2016,c("f","10","s","11"))