# How to calculate mean of data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data.frame "nitrates". And I have to calculate the mean of the values.
When I use:

```
mean(nitrates)
```

it gives me NA with the warning:

> Warning message:
> In mean.default(nitrates) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I want to calculate the mean of data. How can I do that?

Comment: May be this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211779/r-how-to-find-the-mean-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-that-has-non-numeric-speci/46211986

Comment: Try subsetting to the specific column you want in the dataframe using `$`. Something like `mean(nitrates$value)`

Comment: If all columns are numeric, `mean(rowMeans(nitrates))`.

Comment: This would work if it was a matrix, e.g.`mean(as.matrix(mtcars))`.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a dataframe containing mixed string and numeric columns. Since `mean` is defined for numeric values, you need to first select numeric columns and then move forward with averaging. I don't have your dataframe, so I provide an example with another dataframe, but you can replace `storms` with `nitrates`.

```
library('dplyr')
data('storms')

# mean for each column
storms %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% apply(2, mean, na.rm=T)

# mean for each row
storms %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% apply(1, mean, na.rm=T)

# mean over all elements
storms %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% as.matrix() %>% mean(na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download purrr package, and use map_dbl(nitrates, mean). Assuming each column is numeric, you will get the mean for each column.