# how to manipulate dataframe in R shiny app

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

Please I need assistant concerning a shiny code. I want to manipulate a data frame input by separating them into column vector for computation but I keep getting this error

```
Warning in <reactive>(...): NAs introduced by coercion
```

the code is as follows

```
 library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # dataset
  data <- data.frame(e1 = c(3, 7, 2, 14, 66),
             e2 = c(2, 16, 15, 66, 30),
             n1 = c(18, 25, 45, 62, 81), 
             n2= c(20, 30, 79, 64, 89))   
# Application title
titlePanel("Demo"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
     # Input: Upload file
    fileInput(inputId = 'file', label = 'upload the file')
    ),

 # Display Output
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("final")
    )
  )
 )
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   # separating the dataframe into 4 column vectors
   e1 <- reactive(as.numeric(input$file[,1]))
   e2 <- reactive(as.numeric(input$file[,2]))
   n1 <- reactive(as.numeric(input$file[,3]))
   n2 <- reactive(as.numeric(input$file[,4]))

   # File Upload function
   data <- reactive({
   file1 <- input$file
   if(is.null(file1)){return()}
   read.table(file = file1$datapath, sep = ',', header = TRUE)
   })


   output$result <- renderUI({
     y <- (e1()/n1()) - (e2()/n2())
    lg_y <- log(y)
    v2 <- ((n1() - e1())/e1() * n1()) + ((n2() - e2())/e2() * n2())
    w <- 1/v2
    w1 <- sum(w)
    w2 <- sum(w^2)
    c <- w1 - (w2/w1)
    s2 <- w * lg_y
    ybar <- sum(s2)/sum(w)
    Q <- sum(w*((lg_y - ybar)^{2}))# Cochrane homogeneity test statistic
    Q.pval <- reactive(pchisq(Q, k() - 1,lower.tail = FALSE))
    Isqd <- max(100*((Q-(k()-1))/Q),0)
   })
 }
 # Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have searched almost every question on this forum and haven't seen where the question was answered. please I look forward to your help

Comment: You need to provide a sample of the data, otherwise it will be hard to help

Comment: sample of data 4 X 5 dataset i.e. 4 columns and 5 rows

Comment: It's way better if you post a code snippet with the output of `dput(your_data)`, or a subset of it in case it's a very large table.

Comment: @AndreaDodet I have included a hypothetic dataset, I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still can't run the code above because you don't define function `k()`. Also FYI, your `renderUI` is set for `"result"` but your uiOutput is set for `"final"`.

You get the warning `Warning in <reactive>(...): NAs introduced by coercion` because your true data set probably includes a non-numeric in it. I did not get any issues with the data set you provided above.

There are a couple ways forward:

1) Write a function to remove all non-numerics before you process the data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984989/how-to-avoid-warning-when-introducing-nas-by-coercion) for a few examples.

2) Just keep the warning, it is a warning after all so it won't stop your code from running. Currently it turns your non-numerics into NA

3) Use `suppressWarnings()` but that is usually not recommended.

I do have a suggestion to clean up your code though:

```
   # File Upload function
   data <- reactive({
   file1 <- input$file
   if(is.null(file1)){return()}
   read.table(file = file1$datapath, sep = ',', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   })

# separating the dataframe into 4 column vectors
   e1 <- reactive(as.numeric(data()[,1]))
   e2 <- reactive(as.numeric(data()[,2]))
   n1 <- reactive(as.numeric(data()[,3]))
   n2 <- reactive(as.numeric(data()[,4]))
```

Comment: Thanks kelvin. I cleaned up my code as suggested, it worked

Comment: No problem! Feel free to click the green check mark that my answer was correct so it can help other people viewing know it worked.