# R: Error says invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to view gene expression differences between tumour vs normal using a TCGA.GTEX dataset. I am trying to find the log fold change for all columns.

This is the code I applied:

```r
GELogFoldChanges <- apply(TCGA_GTEX_lung[-7], 2, function(x) log(sum(x[1:1011]/sum(x[1012:1299])))
```

But this error occurs:

> Error in sum(x[1:1011]) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

What does this error mean and how should I correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me some columns in `TCGA_GTEX_lung[-7]` are character. You need numeric to calculate sum. You can check this with code `apply(df, 2, function(x) class(x))`. If this is the case, you can convert character to numeric with `as.numeric()`.

**Edit**

```
apply(df,2,function(x) log(sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1:1011]/sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1012:1299], na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding, i tried to convert character to numeric using this code: lapply(TCGA_GTEX_lung,as.numeric) I'm not sure if i did this correctly because this came up: Warning messages:
1: In lapply(LTG, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion. Also when i ran this code again: GELogFoldChanges <- apply(TCGA_GTEX_lung[-7],2,function(x) log(sum(x[1:1011]/sum(x[1012:1299]))). The same error showed up.

Comment: Take a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984989/how-to-avoid-warning-when-introducing-nas-by-coercion), it explains what is the meaning of the warning "NAs introduced by coercion". In brief, this warning tells you some NAs were created during converting. I believe this is also the case for you. You can ignore the NAs when you compute `sum` (`na.rm = TRUE`). See the updated code above. @Tah

Comment: How do i write sum (na.rm = TRUE) into my code? lapply(LTG, as.numeric, sum (na.rm = TRUE) )?

Comment: I edited the code above based on your original `apply` function. Did you see it? `apply(TCGA_GTEX_lung[-7],2,function(x) log(sum(as.numeric(x)[1:1011]/sum(as.numeric(x)[1012:1299], na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE))
  ` @Tah

Comment: Oh no sorry i missed it. I ran the code you gave me but in console a + sign appears now. What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Your original code missed a `)` at end. I added it. Try this `apply(TCGA_GTEX_lung[-7],2,function(x) log(sum(as.numeric(x)[1:1011]/sum(as.numeric(x)[1012:1299], na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)))
 `@Tah

Comment: Oh thanks! i tried it and got this warning: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion.

Comment: This is just warning when NAs were created. You can suppress it using `suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))` as suggested in the post I pointed to `apply(df,2,function(x) log(sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1:1011]/sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1012:1299], na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)))`. Did this solve your question? If so, please accept the answer. @Tah

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!! I think it worked

Comment: Sounds great! Can you accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside my answer? @Tah